# Android studio can not resolve native function

Tags: java, android-studio, java-native-interface

My android studio suggestion not appear create function option . Any jni example dont  run in my android studio . It throws error : cannot resolve corresponding jni function

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade you AndroidStudio to 2.3.1. you must click jni function until a read bulb appear.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJSSA.png)

Comment: You can use add image feature while sharing an image. Dont give link to the image.